# Update SQL Server database from datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, datagridview

I need to update my database on a local PC with `SqlDataAdapter`. The project is Windows Forms. This method selects information from database and returns a `DataTable` to be used as data source for a `DataGridView` :

```
    static string querySelect = "select * from [customers_Sizes] where ID_customers = @ID_customers";
    private  DataSet recivedData;
    static public SqlDataAdapter adapterSize = new SqlDataAdapter(querySelect, connectionString);
    SqlCommandBuilder cmdBuilder;
    public DataTable clientSizes(int ID)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand commSelect = new SqlCommand(querySelect, conn);
            commSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_customers", ID);
            adapterSize = new SqlDataAdapter(commSelect);
            cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapterSize);
            recivedData = new DataSet();
            conn.Open();
            adapterSize.Fill(recivedData);
            table = recivedData.Tables[0];
        }
        return table;
    }
```

This code is for update:

```
public void setNewSizes()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        adapterSize.UpdateCommand = cmdBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
        conn.Open();
        adapterSize.Update(receivedData.Tables[0]);
    }
}
```

In `receivedData` I have exactly the table need to update. I get an error :

> connection string property has not been initialized

So, how can I fix it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are redefining the variable *adapterSize* inside the *clientSizes* method effectively hiding the global variable defined at the class scope.
In this way the global variable defined at the class scope has no info about the parameter ID added to the internal variable and when you try to use it the exception is raised.

Just remove the declaration of adapterSize and use the global variable

```
// SqlDataAdapter adapterSize = new SqlDataAdapter(commSelect);
adapterSize = new SqlDataAdapter(commSelect);
```

Side notes.

1. It is not clear why you have defined all those globals variable with
   the static keyword. If there is no compelling reason to do that, I
   suggest to remove the static keyword and just have class local
   private variables.
2. There is no need to initialize the SqlDataAdapter when you declare it and then again inside the *clientSizes* method, just use the initialization inside the method (of course you need to be sure that nowhere else you use that adapter before calling *clientSizes*
3. You are calling the adapterSize.Fill two times. Again there is no need of the second call. The fill of the DataSet is enough to read the data

Comment: sorry, but this not help me. need to declare scalar variable "@ID"

Comment: Thanks for your side notes, but this did not solve the error.

Comment: Try to move the creation of the SqlCommandBuilder after the creation of the SqlDataAdapter. Leave only the declaration of the SqlCommandBuilder at the global scope

Comment: what do you mean? SqlCommandBuilder is after the SqlDataAdapter.

Comment: Yes, but inside _clientSizes_ you pass an sql command to the adapter and while it has the same commandtext nevertheless is a different command from the previous one initially built by the adapter. However, after a bit of test the position of the SqlCommandBuilder is not the problem. Are you sure that you don't change in any way the Adapter between the _clientSizes_ and _SetSizes_ calls

Comment: _adapterSize = new SqlDataAdapter(commSelect);_ and then _cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapterSize);_ but as I have said this shouldn't change the UpdateCommand produced by the commandbuilder. Can you use the debugger and report what is the commandtext produced by the GetUpdateCommand before the error in the _adapterSize.Update_ line?

Comment: connection string  property has not been initialized

Comment: debugger show this : cmdBuilder.DataAdapter.UpdateCommand = null

Comment: Move the line _con.Open();_ just after the using statement, in both methods

Comment: 'clientSizes' methods worck well, in 'setNewSizes' I moved  after using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {con.Open()//} but not working nevertheless.

Comment: Sorry, but at this point I have no more ideas on what is wrong here. I have created a simple test code with the same logic as yours and there is no problem with that parameter and the UpdateCommand is correctly prepared. I can only think to something else in your code that makes your builder invalid. Check for other points where you use that variables (adapter and builder) to verify if something there messes with the normal flow.

Comment: what would you do, if need to update the table ib base with adapter and commandBuilder ?

Comment: As explained, I have tried a look-a-like code. And it works as expected. This is the more concise way to update. You can call GetChanges on the DataTable and then loop one by one over the rows changed updating the database with a custom command. But this is a more complex work to do than using an Adapter.